# Cannot see volume content in a hostPath mount

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have this very simple container image:

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:8.0-runtime-centos7
VOLUME ["/myvolume"]

# hack to keep the container alive and listening...
CMD exec /bin/bash -c "trap : TERM INT; sleep infinity & wait"
```

I want to deploy it to minikube 0.25.2 (on windows 10) via Kubernetes.
I want `/myvolume` to be mounted to the hostPath `c:\TestDir\` (with syntax `/c/TestDir/`).
`TestDir` is shared with anyone with full control.

I use "Persistent Volume Claims" to achieve the purpose.  This is the .yaml the I use:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    run: hello-mount
  name: hello-mount
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: hello-mount
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: hello-mount
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: docker.io/myid/host_mount_img
        name: hello-mount
        volumeMounts:
        - name: myvolumelbl
          mountPath: /myvolume
      volumes:
      - name: myvolumelbl
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: data-pvc
---
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: data-pv
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  capacity:
    storage: 2Mi
  hostPath:
    path: /c/TestDir/
---
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: data-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Mi
  volumeName: data-pv
```

According to kubernetes dashboard, /myvolume is correctly mounted to /c/TestDir
but when I get into the pod the directory /myvolume is empty - i.e. I cannot see the content of /c/TestDir

Any help is welcome......

Comment: Could you provide additional information: which vm-driver did you use for start minikube. Because there are 2 way to fix the problem.

Comment: Hyper-V (Looking at the Hyper-V manager things seem to be OK)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the [issue with minikube on Hyper-V](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/2002). It didn't fix it. So my advice for you: try to use VirtualBox vm-driver.

Create a shared folder in VirtualBox and use it as a Persistent Volume.